# Relationship between alternating groups and groups of Lie type

Tags: group-theory

The Wikipedia page for [Groups of Lie type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_Lie_type), somewhat cryptically for a beginner such as myself, states the following:

> Alternating groups sometimes behave as if they were groups of Lie type over the field with one element.

As it is my understanding that Groups of Lie type are analogues of Lie groups for finite fields, this seems to imply that Groups of Lie type exhibit some behavior that is correlated with the order of the field they act upon, and this behavior is also observed in alternating groups ocassionally.

If my interpretation is correct, what is that behavior? Otherwise, what is meant by this?

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical (Tits) buildings? If not, it will be a steep hill to climb.

Comment: @MoisheKohan No. What would be a good introductory resource?

Comment: You can start with the Wikipedia article, then, for more in-depth treatment, check Brown's "Buildings." But, as I said, it's a steep climb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Baez provides an accessible exposition to the Field of One Element [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week259.html). The analogy is made intuitively clear there.

In summary, many of the characteristics that apply to the projective special linear group $\text{PSL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for $q + 1$, seem to naturally lead to an interpretation of $\text{PSL}_n(\mathbb{F}_1)$ as an analogue of the symmetric group $\text{S}_n$ (and thus of the alternating groups).

This part is particularly elucidatory:

> When we count things involving $n$-dimensional vector spaces over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, we often get answers that are polynomials in $q$. If we then set $q = 1$, the resulting formulas count analogous things involving $n$-element sets!